# SQL update if exist and insert else and return the key of the row

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table named WORD with the following columns

```
WORD_INDEX INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CONTENT VARCHAR(255),
FREQUENCY INT
```

What I want to do is when I try to add a row to the table if a row with the same CONTENT exits,  I want to increment the FREQUENCY by 1. Otherwise I want to add the row to the table. And then the WORD_INDEX in the newly inserted row or updated row must be returned.
I want to do this in H2 database from one query.
I have tried 'on duplicate key update', but this seems to be not working in H2.

PS- I can do this with 1st making a select query with CONTENT and if I get a empty result set, makeing insert query and otherwise making a update query. But as I have a very large number of words, I am trying to optimize the insert operation. So what I am trying to do is reducing the database interactions I am making.

Comment: Don't you mean _a row with the same CONTENT exists_ ?

Comment: @jpw Yes, Sorry for the mistake. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your edited question .. you can achieve this using a stored procedure like below [A sample code]

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_insert_update_word(IN CONTENT_DATA VARCHAR(255), 
                                       IN FREQ INT, OUT Insert_Id INT)
as 
begin

declare @rec_count int;

select @rec_count = count(*) from WORD where content = CONTENT_DATA;

IF(@rec_count > 0) THEN

UPDATE WORD SET FREQUENCY = FREQUENCY + 1 where CONTENT = CONTENT_DATA;
SELECT NULL INTO Insert_Id;

else

INSERT INTO WORD(CONTENT, FREQUENCY) VALUES(CONTENT_DATA, FREQ);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO Insert_Id;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call your procedure and select the returned inserted id like below

```
CALL sp_insert_update_word('some_content_data', 3, @Insert_Id); 
SELECT @Insert_Id;
```

The above procedure code essentially just checking that, if the same content already exists then perform an `UPDATE` otherwise perform an `INSERT`. Finally return the newly generated auto increment ID if it's `insert` else return `null`.

Comment: Sorry, what I want is if a row with the same CONTENT exits, I want to increment the FREQUENCY by 1. I have edited the question.

Comment: That's why you should clarify everything in your post beforehand. Anyways, see edit in answer with a sample code which will do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First try to update frequency where content = "your submitted data here". If the affected row = 0 then insert a new row. You also might want make CONTENT unique considering it will always stored different data.

Comment: I can do this with 1st making a select query with CONTENT and if I get a empty result set, make insert query and otherwise making a update query. But as I have a very large number of words, I am trying to optimize the insert operation. So what I am trying to do is reducing the database interactions I am making.

Comment: I modified my answer. Check it now. You can get rid of the select query reading the affected rows returned by the update query.

Comment: But the problem is any how I want the WORD_INDEX for the word. So after the update operation, I have to make a select operation.

Comment: You will always make 2 calls: the update call, and depending the result, the insert call (which return the id of the inserted row) or the select call if the update was successful.

Comment: Yes, but what I want is reduce that 2 calls to one.

Comment: SQL is realy fast, even with millions of records, 2 calls shouldn't be a problem. You can indexing the column CONTENT make it unique and index. That will make the query be fast.

Comment: with 500000 words it took me 4 hours to insert (with data added to the other tables actually). And time to insert a word increases with the number of words in the table. Lets say I have 50 million words initially. I don't want to spend lots of time inserting the initial data set. And creating an index will take more time to insert as it take time to create the index also (though it would reduce the time for select queries)

Comment: Read about index property. Trust me. I've been there.